# Apache Nutch crawler how to exclude static folders like; cgi-bin, images, css exclude from nutch crawler?

Tags: apache, hadoop, lucene, mapreduce, nutch

When we run the crawler we see static folders like; /cgi-bin, /images, /css etc. popup in the crawler jobs, we want to exclude them from crawling (not that they end up in indexer) and we don´t want them in indexer, but how we can exclude them in the crawler so it is not occupied with these static folders? Any help is appreciated. Does it help performance, excluding them? as now we see it fetches them for some reason or another. Nutch crawler 1.2, Lucene indexer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add reject rules to the `conf/regex-urlfilter.txt` file.

```
-cgi-bin
-images
-css
```

Note that this must be added before the accept all rule ie. `+.` in the regex file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, appreciate it.

Comment: @user2430823 if u r satisfied with the answer, please upvote and accept the answer

Comment: Hi Tejas, sorry for my late response, the answer is satisfying, however cannot upvote..thanks again for your help appreciate it.